# How to make the profile user forbid to anyone except the own user?

Tags: laravel

I have route:

```
Route::get('@{username}', 'HomePageController@username')->name('user.profile');
```

that route to allow for everyone to see the profile ( contains his info and his cv .. etc ), and in the beginning of register any user user must wait to active his account by the `admin`

I need to see if account of user still under process show above route just for him. and when the account is active open above route for everyone can see his profile.

I tried to create middleware but don't know how can I forbid `the guest user`

My wrong shut:

```
public function username($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username' , '=' , $username)->firstOrFail();

    if($user->active){
        return view('frontend.user_profile',compact('user','projects_last','first_project','whole_projects'));
    }else{
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

What the best scenario to do something like that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
if ($user->active) {
    // Everyone can see
} else {
   if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->username == $username) {
      // only auth and himself can see
   } else {
      // redirect to home page
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($user->active || $username == Auth::user()->username){
        return view('frontend.user_profile',compact('user','projects_last','first_project','whole_projects'));
}else{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object ( in if line )

Comment: this show when I take the url of user that he does not active his account yet, but with the user logged in it works

Comment: add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` at the top of your controller.

Comment: used like this : auth()->user()->username

Comment: how do you want to show a user their profile, if you cannot log in said user?

Comment: the idea my app for users to show up them works or cv or profile etc, so I need to allow user to see his profile even his account under the process but forbid any guest to visit his profile like when he just toke the username and give it to any one like this ( example.com/@username )

Comment: got same error : 
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: if you want to forbid non-logged in users, you can add `$this->middleware('auth');` to your controller __construct() function, it will prevent guests from accessing any of the functions in that controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this

```
if( $username == Auth::user()->username){
   return view('frontend.user_profile',compact('user','projects_last','firs.   t_project','whole_projects'));
}else{
   return abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```php
public function username($username)
{
    $user = User::where(['username' => $username,'status' => 'active'])->firstOrFail();

    if($user && auth()->user()->username == $username){
        return view('frontend.user_profile',compact('user','projects_last','first_project','whole_projects'));
    }else{
        return abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
}
}
```